# setImageAlpha of imageView causing error

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I would like to set the alpha of this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/DashboardView_upBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ab_logo"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/layoutPaddingExtra"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/layoutPaddingLess"
    android:contentDescription="Up"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

I have correctly got the resource in code and called it _upButton. This:

```
_upBtn.setImageAlpha(20);
```

Gives this:

> android.widget.imageview does not contain a definition for setImageAlpha

Why?

Comment: Can you show the code for where you got the resource code?

Comment: Difficult to tell from what you have posted. Are you casting to ImageView?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano No casting. It is of type ImageView.

Comment: setImageAlpha was added in API 16, what version Android are you running?

Comment: @FishStix I'm targeting API 23 with a minimum of 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ImageView needs to be casted to an ImageView to allow the imageview to access the functions within the ImageView.

```
ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
img.setImageAlpha(20);
```

If you are using an API below API-16, then please use:

> img.setAlpha(20);

instead of:

> img.setImageAlpha(20);

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for some reason setAlpha worked even though setImageAlpha should as I'm targeting API 23.